# Is it possible to declare a variable as a different type within the same .gms file?

Tags: gams-math

I have a .gms file with two models.

For each of the models, a particular variable is declared as a continuous variable in one, and a binary variable in another.

Is it possible to write this in GAMS? I do not want to have two variable names for the same variable as I will have double the number of equations for every equation this variable occurs. Plus a lot more problems.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only difference between the two models and if there are no other integer variables, you could just define the variable as binary and solve the model once as mip and once as rmip (relaxed MIP -> continuous).

If there are more differences, you could define the variable as binary and set the [prior](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Variables.html?search=prior#UG_Variables_VariableAttributes) attribute to +INF for the model where you want it to be treated as continuous variable.

Comment: Thank you @Lutz.

The second case applies to me. I will try this out.